# Display image over text on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, prestashop

I have shop at http://prestashop.suszek.info/3-women. On the left side there is a colour. Each colour has a "podgląd" string next to it. Currently when you hover over the text, the image displays below.
How can I display image next to it without a scroll ?

```
<a href="#">(podgląd)<img src="http://prestashop.suszek.info/img/co/13.jpg"></a>

a img {
    display: none;
}
a:hover img {
    display: block;
}
```

btw: ime in null but this is not problem.

Kind regards

Comment: try display: inline when hover

Comment: try display: inline-block when hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the image the following:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 100; 
.. and set margin based on what you want
```

Just make sure you apply these seetings only to the sidebar images.

Answer (score 2):

As you have in your website, the image hover is relative, so you always need the scroll for seeing the image. You can use position absolute for the image, in this case you don´t need the scroll.

Check this out

**CSS**

```
a img {
    display: none;
}
a:hover img {
  position:absolute;
    display: block;
    left:0;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/228/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```css
a:hover img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use a snippet, include the full example. Otherwise, just post the code in a code block

Answer (score 0):

**Change This**

```
a:hover img {
display: block;
}
```

**To This**

```
a:hover img {
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this helping?

```css
a{
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}
img{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:0;
  width:400px;
  
}
a:hover img{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Hover me <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465218550585-6d069382d2a9?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=994&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop="></a>
</br>
<a href="/">Hover me <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465218550585-6d069382d2a9?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=994&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop="></a>
</br>
<a href="/">Hover me <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465218550585-6d069382d2a9?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=994&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop="></a>
</br>
<a href="/">Hover me <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465218550585-6d069382d2a9?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=994&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop="></a>
```